# select from array tmb number from id video

Tags: php, arrays, function

i make a script but i dont get it right way how to make it

Code:

```
 function ID_Photo_TMB( $ID ) {

  $Images_TMB_Data    = array(
   'tmb'               => array(
    'Max'               => '105296',
    'Min'               => '73296',
   ),
   'tmb3'              => array(
    'Max'               => '73295',
    'Min'               => '42966',
   ),
   'tmb2'              => array(
    'Max'               => '42965',
    'Min'               => '1',
   ),
  );


 }
```

Lets say $ID = 32332 how i can make the function to return me the tmb (number) what ID is between range of Max / Min of tmb or tmb2 or tmb3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have expanded your function to include the code required to satisfy your requirement.

```
function ID_Photo_TMB( $ID ) {

  $Images_TMB_Data    = array(
   'tmb'               => array(
    'Max'               => '105296',
    'Min'               => '73296',
   ),
   'tmb3'              => array(
    'Max'               => '73295',
    'Min'               => '42966',
   ),
   'tmb2'              => array(
    'Max'               => '42965',
    'Min'               => '1',
   ),
  );

 foreach ($Images_TMB_Data as $key => $val) {
     if ($ID >= $val['Min'] && $ID <= $val['Max']) return $key;
 }
}
```

Comment: i try your code but hope someone can tell me how i can include this on tpl file, $videos[i].VID its the video ID, i try to include this way {$videos[i].VID|ID_Photo_TMB} but didn't work ... how i can make this ?

Comment: yes ... i use avs script if you know this script but i have a problem with the limits of the folder on folder ... max limits of folders on folder is 32k ...

Comment: i am sorry i am not familer with avs, right now i am in the middle of something and don't have time to look at avs to answer your second question. Maybe you can ask on S0

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($Images_TMP_Data as $key => $value) {
  if ($ID >= $value['Min'] && $ID <= $value['Max']) {
    return $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you forgot to add max in condition